# Android Dropbox access. Enabling user to access the whole dropbox

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing an app so that a user can access all folders in their dropbox. I've already got production status for my app. All I need to do now is to find a way to either open the dropbox app from mine, or somehow list the contents of the dropbox in my app. Either way, I would like some help.

The purpose of this access would be to allow the user to pick files from their dropbox folder which they will then download into the app.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You should set OAuth dropbox access token to your app

Comment: The authentication works. I've already set that up. Sorry I didn't mention that.